# Hdfs count command tweak

Tags: hadoop

I am using below command to assign a value, Is there a alternative way to get by tweaking the code

```
var=hdfs dfs -ls /hdfs_path/ | grep col=2020_03 | awk -F' ' '{system("hdfs dfs -count "$8)}' | awk -F' ' '{if ($3 != 0) print $4}' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'|sort -nr | uniq | head -1
```

Basically i am need to find the latest month value that holds data in hdfs directory. For eg

```
hdfs_path/col=2020_03_21/data.part - this has no data
    hdfs_path/col=2020_03_20/data.part - this has data
    hdfs_path/col=2020_03_19/data.part - this has data
```

hence output should be `val = 2020_03_20`

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain what the purpose of the code is? What does the command do?

Answer (score 1):

Just some comments on the last part of the command.

Since you don't use any of the extra features of `uniq`, you can drop replace

`sort -nr | uniq`

with

`sort -nr -u`

---

I don't see a reason to sort in reverse, and then take the first line with `head -1`, when you could instead use `tail -1`.

`sort -nu | tail -1`

---

While outputting duplicated lines to tail might take some time if there is a lot of duplication, since you only actually want the final line, you can probably drop the `-u` flag in `sort`. If you wanted the most recent 3 dates, you'd need to add it back in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way possible to replace the hdfs -count command , i mean alternative to that

Comment: @user2672739 I have no idea. I don't know anything about hdfs, sorry.